# What to look for in language schools to learn especially good english “speaking”?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, learning

I am from a country which does not speak English for daily use. I can understand written english well (except Shakespeare). I can speak and pronounce "some" words very well. I have visited UK for 1 week and I had no important problems during my visit.

Here comes my question: I want to go to a language school or some another courses but I don't know what to look for; I am not looking for a way to extend my vocabulary or grammer. That would be good for sure, but; I "mostly" extend my english "speaking" and "pronunciation". Especially, speaking like anchors. (I am not talking about the abilities and being an anchor. I mean "media language/media pronunciation". I know I have to live in US or UK (I also know they are almost fully different) to extend my understanding of words and pronunciations with my ears, this is not currently what I am looking for.

Even my current question may have lots of grammar mistakes and it may be a mixture of US/UK english.

Maybe I can summarize it like this: I want to learn "beautiful speaking" technics and to do this, I want to understand if there are any language schools for foreigners specialized for "beautiful speaking".

Comment: I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQpkZ8gfTCo) on YouTube; I don't know if that's the kind of thing you're looking for or not. In any event, we handle resource requests by adding them to the [resources thread on meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english). I've added a link to the YouTube section. If others know of any resources that might help you out, I'd encourage them to add more links as well.

Comment: Thank you @J.R. this is useful. I seeked the video forward a bit and saw that it really includes information that I am interested in.